# JAVA Rest Service with Spring constructor needs to have too many parameters

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

first question here. Im currently working on some Rest services using Spring Data and everything has been working fine but im facing this problem:

One of my entities needs to have a 22 parameter constructor in order to work. Its the only way spring is able to map it correctly, if i try to work around this bad designed constructor i get the following:

Could not locate appropriate constructor on class : com.x.core.model.xxx; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate appropriate constructor on class : com.x.core.model.xxxx

However if I leave the constructor as it is (with 22 parameters) checklist will throw an error because of the number of parameters on the constructor.

Ive been searching everywhere for a solution but havent found one.

Keep in mind that i changed variables name in order to keep companys data protected.

Thanks

```
@Entity
@IdClass(MYCLASS.class)
@XmlRootElement
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(name = "MYCLASS.findAll",
            query
            = "SELECT * from table",
            resultClass = MYCLASS.class, resultSetMapping = "MyClassMap"
    )
})
@SqlResultSetMappings({
    @SqlResultSetMapping(name = "MyClassMap",
            classes = {
                @ConstructorResult(targetClass = MYCLASS.class,
                        columns = {
                            @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Integer.class)//etc... THIS IS CORRECT
                           ,})})
})
public class MYCLASS implements Serializable {

@Id
private Integer paramid;
@Id
private Integer param1;
private String param2;
@Id
private long paramx;
private Integer paramx;
private String paramx;
private Double paramx;
private String paramx;
private Double paramx;
private String paramx;
private String paramx;
private String paramx;
private Double paramx;
private Double paramx;
private Integer paramx;
private Integer paramx;
private Integer paramx;
private Integer paramx;
private Integer paramx;

public MYCLASS(Integer paramx, Integer paramx, String paramx, long paramx, Integer paramx, String paramx, Double paramx, String  paramx, Double paramx, String paramx, String paramx, String paramx, Double paramx, Double paramx, Integer paramx, Integer paramx, Integer paramx, Integer GASTO, Integer paramx) {
    this.paramx = paramx;
    this.paramx = paramx;
    this.paramx = paramx;
    this.paramx = paramx;
    this.paramx = paramx;
    this.paramx = paramx;
    this.paramx = paramx;
    this.paramx = paramx;
    this.paramx = paramx;
    this.paramx = paramx;
    this.paramx = paramx;
    this.paramx = paramx;
    this.paramx = paramx;
    this.paramx = paramx;
    this.paramx = paramx;
    this.paramx = paramx;
    this.paramx = paramx;
    this.paramx = paramx;
    this.paramx = paramx;
}//TOO MANY PARAMETERS!!!!!



//getters ,setters, equals and hash
```

Comment: Write the default constructor `public MYCLASS(){}`

Comment: I have tried that already, it would throw Could not locate appropriate constructor on class :S

Comment: Isn't that a result of using ConstructorResult? Seems like your issues stem from that.

Comment: Yep, it is. Im going to be testing it using EntityResult and ColumnResult and see if it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it !
It seems that when you are in need of a resultsetmap for a nonmanaged entity you can go straight and use @ColumnResult instead and it will work. This way you will avoid using a constructor.

```
@SqlResultSetMappings({
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "map",
        columns = {
                        @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Integer.class)})})
```